# How can I deploy only a select set of stored procedures in a DACPAC deployment?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I have a visual studio project which contains a database project. I create an executable which performs a software update and part of that update is to update the database. Some of the stored procedures are dependent on a linked server existing which gets created as part of the executable too. The problem is that this functionality is optional and the linked server won't connect on some client machines. But the DACPAC fails because the linked server can't connect. I am using sqlpackage.exe to deploy the .dacpac file.

Is there some way that I can deploy either all or only some of the stored procedures? Or maybe I can set a flag to ignore linked server errors? Or maybe there is an alternative method to using sqlpackage/dacpac?

One option I thought of is to convert the stored procedures that contain the linked server to dynamic SQL.

Having the database in visual studio and therefore source control is important.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

This is fairly easy to do. You can see your database project in visual studio. I would recommend removing the stored procs that are problematic and merging those back in to master. Then I would take out a feature branch and point again to the DB you have the stored procs on and use the schema compare to get those back as well (even the ones that don't work well so that you don't lose them). Push the commit up to the feature branch repo. Then,now that you have the problematic stored procs in source control + the shippable version in master-- you can go ahead and thruough visual studio "publish" through the database project into the DBs you want the selected objects.

If you haven't checked in anything to master-- you can do the schema compare and select all objects except those that are problematic and update your database project. and merge that to master. If this doesn't make sense, please comment on this answer and I'm happy to give more detail.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I came across this. Still working on to implement this to solve my problem. Might help your cause too.

> Download the filter from:
> https://agilesqlclub.codeplex.com/releases/view/610727 put the dll
> into the same folder as sqlpackage.exe and add these command line
> parameters to your deployment:
>
> /p:AdditionalDeploymentContributors=AgileSqlClub.DeploymentFilterContributor
> /p:AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments="SqlPackageFilter=IgnoreSchema(BLAH)”
>
> This will neither deploy, drop or alter anything in the BLAH schema.

More details on
https://the.agilesql.club/2015/01/howto-filter-dacpac-deployments/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)